# Operations with a vector not starting at the origin

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

[image]

Suppose we have the vectors $\vec{AB} ,\vec{AC} ,\vec{AD} $ like in the image , and all of their coordinates are relatively to the two preprinted axes , say I want $\vec{AB} \cdot \vec{AD}$ , is it enough to consider the dot product between their components like they are now , or I should make a traslation of the vector so that they starts at the origin ? 
(I have never done linear algebra so I hope to have been clear enough)

Comment: I think that if you want $\vec {AB}.\vec {AD}$, then you must simply consider the components as they are now. (you want  $\vec {AB}.\vec {AD}$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The components of the vector $\vec{AB}$ as they are now and the components after translating to the origin *are the same*, so it doesn't matter. Note that the components of $\vec{AB}$ are obtained by subtracting the *coordinates* of $A$ from those of $B$, **this difference doesn't change when $A$ and $B$ are translated together**.

In your example we have approximately
\begin{align*}
\vec{AB} &\approx \begin{pmatrix} (-4.5)-(-1.2) \\ 2.6-5.6 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -3.3 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix},
\\
\vec{AC} &\approx \begin{pmatrix} (1.5)-(-1.2) \\ 3.1-5.6 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2.7 \\ -2.5 \end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}
so that
$$
\vec{AB}\cdot\vec{AC} \approx (-3.3)\times2.7 + (-3)\times(-2.5) = 1.41.
$$

Comment: right right I was just confused about the fact that I had to subtracte the coordinates of $A$ from those of $B$. Thank you!